# Vue : prevent soring in computed list when editing content

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a computed, sorted list which is also editable.. (input with v-model="....")..

This works well, except for that the list sorts itself when typing new text in the inputs. I want to prevent that somehow..

Is there any way to prevent the sorting to trigger on ex. keypress or by using some kind of custom property like "new", "editmode" ?

**Computed prop :**

```
nluData() {
            return orderby(this.$store.getters.nlujson.filter(item => {
                return item.intent.toLowerCase() === this.selectedIntent
            }), ['intent', 'text'], ['asc', 'asc'])
        },
```

**Inputs :**

```
<div v-for="(item, key, index) in nluData">
    <input v-model="item.intent" class="form-control">
    ......
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.lazy` modifier that prevents syncing after an input event and that will wait for a change event.

```
<input v-model.lazy="item.intent" class="form-control">
```

See [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy) for the docs.

When you don't want to sort the list after a change event, you could add a boolean (`sortList` for example) that you would have to set manually and can add to `nluData()`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @piscator :) Didn't know about this feature, and it was indeed useful!.. Seems like the change triggered (magically?) on field-exit / focus change ?

Comment: You're welcome @TerjeNygård! A change event for input and textarea elements is indeed triggered after a focus change.